# Different pump flow behaviour in common circuit?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hvac, multiphase-flow

I want to evaluate a system of closed circuit. Two hot water chillers are serving two different areas and have different capacities but their hot water source is common due to which we have combined the two pumps circuits at one point to make a common header. The flow and pressure of both pumps are different i.e. 118 cubic meters per hour and differential pressure is 180 feet while the second has 170 cubic meters per hour and differential pressure is 230 feet.

Will it work properly, if not then what I need to do?
Secondly, if one chiller cooling requirement is reduce to 75% then how will I balance the pump flow?

Comment: Supply a diagram showing what you are describing.

Comment: do you mean an absorption chiller that runs off hot water?